# How to create correct database scheme of cooking site?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I want to make a cooking site but don't know the correct was to build database.

My models are: `Recipe` and `Ingredient`.

Ingredient in recipe should be autocomplete field. The problem is that user can put there any text. ("cucumber" or "cucamber") and it will be different ingredients.

I want to make a search by ingredients and links to them. What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A recipe has many items, which in turn keeps a reference to an ingredient, an amount and a measure type. So you can go with:

```
rails generate model Recipe name:string description:text
rails generate model Item recipe:references ingredient:references amount:decimal measure:string 
rails generate model Ingredient name:string
```

and then add to your classes:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
  has_many :ingredients, :through => :items


  # this allows things like @recipes = Recipe.using("cucumber")
  scope :using, lambda do |text| 
    joins(:ingredients).where("ingredients.name LIKE ?", "%#{text}%")
  end
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :ingredient

  VALID_MEASURES = %w[oz kg tbsp] # use for "select" tags in forms
  validates :measure, :inclusion => VALID_MEASURES
end

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
end
```

From here you start building your views, autocomplete, whatever your imagination allows.